# apps-script: preventing multiple firing of handlers?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm seeing multiple submissions on a form, presumably because someone is double-clicking a submit button. Is there a good way to prevent this in GAS? I suppose I could set up a global variable via JSON, and use that to determine whether or not to execute the handler, but it seems a bit clunky.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

create a client Handler that disables the submit button before the rest of your code is executed.

You can add a client handler anywhere you would add a server handler of any type, and it works entirely on the client without any server roundtrip.

See Serge insas comment below!

Comment: A *client* handler? That's interesting. Like the `var handler =  app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setEnabled(false)` example on the UI page? This presumably has to be inside the server handler, to re-enable it? In which case, isn't it running too late to be of any use?

Comment: I don't get it. For the client handler to disable the button, it must presumably have run in response to the button click. In which case the `disable` call can't be posted inside the server handler, but has to be posted in `doGet`. If this right, then how does the client handler arrange for execution of the server handler code? Or is the client handler guaranteed to run before the server handler? And so on...

Comment: the client handler will trigger together with the server handler and by disabling the button will prevent double clicking but it does not interfere with the current server handler execution. They are triggered simultaneously but run independently. If you need to re-enable the button for some reason you can do it at the end of the serverhandler (eventually with an added delay) or use another button specially designed to "re-submit" the form .(last note : both handlers must be defined in the main doGet function since they both have to exist before the button is clicked)